# Drupal 7 tokens and img tags

Tags: drupal-7, token, drupal-webform

I am using Drupal 7, webform and webform2pdf modules to create an application form, that once filled out, will generate a PDF with all of the information from the applicant.

Problem that I am having is that the fields I set up for uploading a .jpg head shot and a .pdf of a short explanation are showing as links instead of just listing the content.

I am using tokens generated from the webform components to dynamically fill the content into the PDF.

for example [submission:value:recent_photo]

is there a special syntax I need to display the image instead of just the link?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution i've found to solve the same problem (Drupal 7, Webform 4).
Type this function in MYADMINTHEME/template.php

```
function MYADMINTHEME_webform_display_file($variables) {
    $element = $variables['element'];
    $current_path = current_path();
    $file = $element['#value'];
    $filemime = !empty($file) ? $element['#value']->filemime : '';

    if (substr_count($current_path, 'downloadpdf') && in_array($filemime, array('image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png'))){
        if ($element['#format'] == 'text')
            return !empty($file) ? webform_file_url($file->uri) : t('no upload');

        $url = drupal_realpath($file->uri);
        return '<img src="' . $url . '"/>';
    } else {
        $url = !empty($file) ? webform_file_url($file->uri) : t('no upload');
        return !empty($file) ? ($element['#format'] == 'text' ? $url : l($file->filename, $url)) : ' ';
    }

}
```